# odoo: make a default value

Tags: odoo, default-value

how to make a default value to an object with different view ? 
as an example Customer and supplier view: 
when you create a customer the customer field is checked
and in supplier the supplier field is checked
I tried to do a default value and it doesent work !

Comment: You should have to show some efforts. What you have tried so far ?

Comment: I tried a lot of creating new views and actions,

Comment: might be this will be helpful to you. http://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2015/05/how-to-set-default-value-in-odoo.html

Comment: I meant that edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Comment: I want the default value depend on the view like Customers/Suppliers

Comment: @Odedra not that default value I'm looking for, I want it to depend on menu or view like partner